# How do i post a form in rails using ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app that I need to use Ajax to post on my model.

I have only this line in my filename.js.erb

```
$('#new-band a').html('<%= j render 'form'%>')
```

Here is my error:

```
Showing /<snip>/ajax/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x00007fad63eb3b98>:0x00007fad5e2c13f8>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer but try adding parens: `j(render('form'))` to be sure it is being parsed as intended by Ruby.

Comment: Where is `filename.js.erb` being called? can you add the controller ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your single quote to double quotes around the form. For example:

```
$('#new-band a').html('<%= j render 'form'%>')
```

Changes to:

```
$('#new-band a').html('<%= j render "form" %>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#new-band a').html("<%= j render(:partial => 'form') %>");
```